# Create thee divs in one line and 4th div in bottom. CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to create html page the next vision. Location of divs 1,2 and 3 in one line was done, but with 4th div I have some troubles and can't make it.

Comment: Please include your code thus far, preferably in a jsfiddle.

Comment: Please explain more what you want, fixed heights and widths? Perhaps add you html and css code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should post your code to see whats wrong with it.. But i made the example for you.

Here you go, you could use float.

**Html Code:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="first">
    </div>
    <div id="second">
    </div>
    <div id="third">
    </div>
    <div id="fourth">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Css Code:**

```
#wrapper{width:300px; margin:0;}
#first { height:300px; width:100px; background:black; float:left;}
#second{ height:250px; width:100px; background:red;float:left;}
#third{ height:250px; width:100px; background:green;float:left;}
#fourth{ height:50px; width:200px; background:blue;float:left;}
```

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/J2aLv/)**

Comment: Thanks, this variant works fine and is I want to find.

Comment: Okay nice! Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that uses non-fixed heights and widths.  The key is wrapping the subsections in `divs` as well and styling accordingly.  `div` is short for division after all.

```
<div class="left">
     1
</div>
<div class="right">
    <div class="second-third-wrapper">
        <div class="second">
            2 
        </div>
        <div class="third">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div  class="fourth">
        4
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pb5NX/2/

The `divs` then use percentage height and widths to size them properly.  These percentages take up a percentage of the parent element (the `<body>`, which then inherits from the `<html>`), so the parents height needs to be set as well.

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.left {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

If you want them a fixed size, you can just set a specific `height` and `width` style on the  specific elements and the percentages will do the rest.

Comment: Thanks, this variant works fine and is I want to find. It similar to first answer. Thanks for help!